# Get all the Document Libraries in the Site - URL REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get use the REST API to develop a custom promoted link type of library. I am the following end-point but can't seem to find the URL of the library:

```
_api/Web/Lists $select=Title,Description,
Created&$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101 and hidden eq false
```

I also tried using list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl but I am getting an error.  Am I suppose include any reference/script?

Comment: Are trying to GET library? Or creating an item in library?

Comment: all the libraries in the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_api/web/lists?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101 and hidden eq false&$expand=RootFolder` this works for me it gets all lists and server relative URL according to filters applied.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. If you have any documentation for this that would be great.

Comment: This should work as I have used this previously in my code as well, no concrete documetation but you can find the references  here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx